# The new line issue while PowerShell to word file

Tags: powershell, ms-word, newline, flatopc

Trying to transfer an object[]/list of strings/strings (containing all the files name in a directory) from PowerShell to Word file by replacing template variable with the data. In PowerShell, it shows up with a new line, but in the Word output, the new line does not show up.
As in shell, it's  LF or just CR where Word may want CRLF. Therefore, tried but not work

```
$DATA -replace "`n", "`r`n"
```

FYI: Initially Word template transferred to XML, then replaced the template variable with the content, and finally DOCX using ConvertTo-FlatOpc

```
#$workdir: Directory to the path whose file name we want to get
#$TEMPLATE: Word document whose Variable we gonna replace
#$OUTPUTFILE: Output file with the data

$DATA = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $workdir | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | % {Write-Output $_.Name}

'ConvertTo-FlatOpc $TEMPLATE -OutputFormat Text > $temp_source_xml'
   

(Get-Content template_source.xml) | ForEach-Object {

$_    -replace "%FL%", "$DATA" `

} | Set-Content ("$temp_out_xml")
    
$a = 'Get-Content $temp_out_xml'
'ConvertFrom-FlatOpc $a $OUTPUTFILE'
"$OUTPUTFILE generated"
```

**The output we want in DOCX**
Azure.Core.dll
Azure.Core.xml
Azure.Identity.dll
Azure.Identity.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml

**The output we are getting in DOCX**
Azure.Core.dll Azure.Core.xml Azure.Identity.dll Azure.Identity.xml log4net.dll log4net.xml

Comment: `'...'` is a verbatim string literal, not a command. Remove the enclosing single quotes around your `ConvertFrom-FlatOpc` calls to actually make a call.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside that you accidentally enclosed your `ConvertFrom-FlatOpc` commands in `'...'` (which makes them verbatim string literals that are output as such):

- Your `$DATA` variable contains an *array* of file names.

  - As an aside: you could more simply fill the variable as follows:

    ```
    $DATA = (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $workdir).Name
    ```
- In your replacement operation, `$_ -replace "%FL%", "$DATA"` you're *stringifying* this array by embedding it in an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).

  - PowerShell **stringifies arrays by joining the (stringified) elements of the array with a *space character* as the separator** by default<sup>[1]</sup>; e.g. `"$( 'a', 'b' )"` yields verbatim `a b`.
- Since the second RHS operand of the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), the *substitution expression*, expects a *single string*, the same kind of stringification would happen *implicitly*, even without the enclosure in `"..."`; e.g., `'ab-c' -replace 'c', ('d', 'e')` yields verbatim `ab-d e`

---

Therefore, **if you want to use `-replace` to replace strings with *multi-line* strings, you'll have to construct them explicitly**, which you can easily do with the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join):

```
$_ -replace "%FL%", ($DATA -join "`r`n")
```

<sup>Note: Presumably, `` "`n" `` will do. You could also use `[Environment]::NewLine`, which uses the platform-appropriate newline format.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] While it's possible to set a different separator via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), that is rarely done in practice.</sup>